# Change cursor to pointer on ion-input

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there a way to apply `cursor: pointer;` to an `ion-input` element? It seems like no matter what I do, it's showing the default i-beam cursor.

My input:

```
<ion-input [readonly]="true" [placeholder]="getPlaceholder() | translate"></ion-input>
```

CSS I've tried:

```
ion-input {
  input {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

ion-input {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ion-input::part(input) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And I've tried the `!important` tag on all of these.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a working stackblitz which shows the solution.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-a8vavn)

In order to solve this type of problem:

1. Right click on the ion input element.
2. Observe that your element is on the shadow dom.
   [image]
3. Further observe that what you are really interested in is the native input which has a class of native-input.
4. Add the following CSS to correctly pierce the shadowDom.

```
::ng-deep ion-input .native-input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Using ::ng-deep will pierce the dom, and the rest takes care of the correct selection for style application.